# VBA Countif Uppercase

Tags: excel, vba, loops, countif

I'm trying to count the number of instances of a cell containing all uppercase characters in a user defined range, I've got some code already which loops through and highlights those uppercase cells correctly, but I'm struggling to apply that logic to VBA's Countif function. Here's the code I've got but its giving a mismatch error:

```
'count instances of all caps
Dim allcaps As Long
allcaps = Application.CountIf(Range(rngCompany.Cells(1, 1), rngCompany.Cells(Lastrow, 1)), UCase(Range(rngCompany.Cells(1, 1), rngCompany.Cells(Lastrow, 1))))


MsgBox "There are " & allcaps & " uppercase company names to review."
```

The code which is highlighting the cells correctly is:

```
'Highlight all caps company names for review
With ws
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        ' checks if cells in company name col are uppercase
        If rngCompany.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value = UCase(rngCompany.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            wbk1.Sheets(1).Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '6: Yellow
        Else
            End If
        
    Next i
End With
```

Is there a way to make the countif code work in a similar way within the loop? Thanks.

Comment: Please include the missing parts of your code, like where `rngCompany` is set - some of your snippets don't make sense. `rngCompany.EntireColumn.Cells(i,1).Value` - why do you include `EntireColumn` in here? What is the purpose of your `With` statement in your second snippet? I don't see you using `ws` anywhere in there. What is `Lastrow`? Too many missing pieces of your puzzle.

Comment: If your second block is working why not add a counter inside the loop if you need to track how many upper-case values you have?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
Function AllCapsCount(Target As Range) As Long
    With Target.Parent
        AllCapsCount = .Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(" & Target.Address & ",UPPER(" & Target.Address & ")))")
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim's suggestion of simply adding a counter within the loop was the simplest solution for me, after a long day I'd overlooked that way forward!

Code example for anyone coming across this in future:

```
AllCapsCount = 0
With ws
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        ' checks if cells in company name col are uppercase
        If rngCompany.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value = UCase(rngCompany.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            wbk1.Sheets(1).Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '6: Yellow
        AllCapsCount = AllCapsCount + 1
        Else
            End If
        
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight and Count Cells if UCase but no LCase

```vb
Sub TESTgetAllCapsRange()
    Dim rngCompany As Range
    Set rngCompany = Range("A2:E11")
    rngCompany.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = getAllCapsRange(rngCompany)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Dim AllCaps As Long: AllCaps = rng.Cells.CountLarge
        If AllCaps > 1 Then
            MsgBox "There are " & AllCaps _
                & " uppercase company names to review."
        Else
            MsgBox "There is 1 uppercase company name to review."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no uppercase company names to review."
    End If
End Sub

Function getAllCapsRange(rng As Range) As Range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim tRng As Range
        Dim aRng As Range
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each aRng In rng.Areas
            For Each cel In aRng.Cells
                If Not IsError(cel) Then
                    If containsUCaseButNoLCase(cel.Value) Then
                        buildRange tRng, cel
                    End If
                End If
            Next cel
        Next aRng
        If Not tRng Is Nothing Then
            Set getAllCapsRange = tRng
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function containsUCaseButNoLCase(ByVal CheckString As String) As Boolean
    ' Check if there is an upper case character.
    If StrComp(CheckString, LCase(CheckString), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
        ' Check if there are no lower case characters.
        If StrComp(CheckString, UCase(CheckString), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            containsUCaseButNoLCase = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Sub buildRange(ByRef BuiltRange As Range, AddRange As Range)
    If Not AddRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set BuiltRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
        Else
            Set BuiltRange = AddRange
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```